# Most efficient way to have a vector take the contents of an array?

Tags: c++

I know `myvec.data()` returns a pointer to the vector's data. In this case, I'd like to set the vector's internal data to point to my own array, allocated like so:

```
double* my_array = new double[amount];
```

I know I could do this:

```
std::vector<double> my_vec;

for (double i : my_array) my_vec.push_back(i);

delete [] my_array;
```

but I'm asking if there's a way to have it be done without O(n) of extra memory (i.e, just make it point to my array and provide some info about it).

Would something like:

```
my_vec.insert(std::end(my_vec), std::begin(my_array), std::end(my_array));
```

do the job? I have a feeling `std::move` may be needed, but I'm not sure where?

According to the comments, this is a horrible idea, and no you cannot, so let's say `my_array` is now another vector, would this work:

```
my_vec = std::vector<double>(std::move(my_other_vec))
```

?

Comment: I don't know a lot of c++, but could you use make a custom allocator that takes a std::array as backing storage for a vector? :P (this is a joke answer by the way. If the array was using automatic storage, you'd have to worry about lifetime sync and that would be a mess)

Comment: What do you mean @starball ? `std::vector` uses an array internally, and an array (as far as I'm aware) is just contiguously allocated data of a type, and is not a `std::` type

Comment: Not with vector but you should take a look at `std::span`

Comment: No, `std::vector` is quite a bit more complex than just an array internally. For starters, it has to have memory with no objects in it, to accommodate for further growth. It doesn't use `new[]` for sure.

Comment: Already smelling like an XY problem. `std::vector` manages memory for the collection and it cannot be set to reference something externally that you create yourself (although you could probably force it via the allocator but that's messy). There is really no reason to do this anyway when you can specify the size of the vector and point of construction or after it's been instantiated. You can also pass it init data at construction too. You could of course use a `std::span` to provide access to the data you allocate but again, why would you when the `std::vector` does everything for you already.

Comment: May I ask why you're using raw pointer for my_array?

Comment: Why do you have a c-array in the 1st place?  Get rid of it and use a `std::vector`, job done; no need to move or copy anything.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious this is deep in the program. the `std::vector` was based on dynamic user data and the `new double[]` was not, so it made sense to do it this way. I don't want to refactor the program to use `std::span`, of my methods mentioned above, would either way be more efficient than the other?

Comment: I did it to make myself feel better about the tiny performance boost from using the C-array, plus I'm new to STLs and more comfortable in C, so...

Comment: I could do that @RichardCritten , at that point, would I just use `my_vec.swap(my_other_vec);` or would it be `my_vec.swap(std::move(my_other_vec));` ?

Comment: Assuming the array was allocated with `new[]` and you cannot change it to `std::vector` at creation place, `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` could be an option as well. But only consider that if you really can't use `vector` since the beginning.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious when you say pass it init data for construction, could I pass it another vector to construct itself with? Say, something like : `my_vec = std::vector<double>(std::move(my_other_vec));` ??

Comment: I can @Yksisarvinen , and that's what I'm now planning.

Comment: tiny performance boosts are not the things that should be interesting you. also, i don't see why a c array would give you even a tiny one

Comment: Yes and you can pass it a naked array with a size if you like. See the [`std::vector` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) and some bomb diggity [`std::vector` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for information on what's available to you

Comment: The question is not being well-received because it's not particularly clear what you want and what the goal is. Based on the comments, it's reading like you have a dynamically allocated and manually managed array and you want to turn it into view it with a `std::vector`. That's not what `vector` is generally used for, it is an owner of data, not a viewer, so understanding why you want to do this is paramount to offering up good alternatives.

Comment: @NeilButterworth perhaps I was overthinking it, but it is worth it to note that a vector is more weighty than a raw pointer. Now that I'm really thinking about it, it would be on the order of nano or microseconds.

Comment: Micro-optimizations will waste more time than you realize, avoid them like herpes. What's more weighty, the `std::vector` or all the extra code you write to ensure your naked array is used and managed properly? Or are they just as performant or does the difference really matter for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @user8393252 `double* my_array = new double[amount];` -- Any modern C++ code that has anything looking like that is discouraged in this day and age of C++.  Maybe you should take a step back and see *why* this was done in this way.  Was it simply a lack of knowledge about the standard library?  Was it legacy code, before 1998, before `std::vector` became an official, standard class?

Comment: No, what's described cannot be done in C++, C++ vectors don't support anything like that.

Comment: *plus I'm new to STLs and more comfortable in C, so* - there isn't a single line of C in the code you show. Just noting.

Comment: *Now that I'm really thinking about it, it would be on the order of nano or microseconds.* -- We do not know the flow of your code as to when, where, or how many times that line of code using `new[]` is executed.  If it's executed multiple times (along with `delete[]`), you may possibly have *slower* code than if you used a `std::vector`.  Depending on how your code is structured, simply calling `std::vector::resize()` instead of `new[]/delete[]` repeatedly would drastically speed up the code.

Comment: *"Now that I'm really thinking about it, it would be on the order of nano or microseconds."* - Think about it? So you did not benchmark? Just engaged in FUD driven design?

Comment: the things you need to know in order to use a C dynamically-allocated array, such as its size, requires extra variables, which the C++ vector gives you far more conveniently, and at no extra cost.